# memcpy vs strcat

Tags: c, string, memory, network-programming

Seems to be a basic question but I would rather ask this to clear up than spend many more days on this.I am trying to copy data in a buffer which I receive(recv call) which will be then pushed to a file. I want to use memcpy to continuously append/add data to the buffer until the size of buffer is not enough to hold more data where I than use the realloc. The code is as below.

```
int vl_packetSize = PAD_SIZE + (int)p_size - 1; // PAD_SIZE is the size of char array sent 
                        //p_size is the size of data to be recv. Same data size is used by send 
int p_currentSize = MAX_PROTO_BUFFER_SIZE;
int vl_newPacketSize = p_currentSize;

char *vl_data = (char *)malloc(vl_packetSize);
memset((char *)vl_data,'\0',vl_packetSize);


/* Allocate memory to the buffer */
vlBuffer = (char *)malloc(p_currentSize);
memset((char *)vlBuffer,'\0',p_currentSize);
char *vlBufferCopy = vlBuffer;

if(vlBuffer==NULL)
    return ERR_NO_MEM;

/* The sender first sends a padding data of size PAD_SIZE followed by actual data. I want to ignore the pad hence do vl_data+PAD_SIZE on memcpy */
if((p_currentSize - vl_llLen) < (vl_packetSize-PAD_SIZE)){
  vl_newPacketSize +=vl_newPacketSize;
  char *vlTempBuffer = (char *)realloc(vlBufferCopy,(size_t)vl_newPacketSize);
  if(vlTempBuffer == NULL){
     if(debug > 1)
    fprintf(stdout,"Realloc failed:%s...Control Thread\n\n",fn_strerror_r(errno,err_buff));
    free((void *)vlBufferCopy);
    free((void *)vl_data);
    return ERR_NO_MEM;  
      }
    vlBufferCopy = vlTempBuffer;
    vl_bytesIns = vl_llLen;
    vl_llLen = 0;
    vlBuffer = vlBufferCopy+vl_bytesIns;
    fprintf(stdout,"Buffer val after realloc:%s\n\n",vlBufferCopy);
}

memcpy(vlBuffer,vl_data+PAD_SIZE,vl_packetSize-PAD_SIZE);

/*
fprintf(stdout,"Buffer val before increment:%s\n\n",vlBuffer);
fprintf(stdout,"vl_data length:%d\n\n",strlen(vl_data+PAD_SIZE));
fprintf(stdout,"vlBuffer length:%d\n\n",strlen(vlBuffer));
*/

vlBuffer+=(vl_packetSize-PAD_SIZE);
vl_llLen += (vl_packetSize-PAD_SIZE);
vl_ifNotFlush = 1;
//fprintf(stdout,"Buffer val just before realloc:%s\n\n",vlBufferCopy);
}
```

Problem: Whan ever I fputs the data into the file later on. Only the first data recv/added to buffer is gets into the file. 
Also when I print the value of vlBufferCopy(which points to first location of data returned by malloc or realloc) I get the same result.
If I decrease the size by 1, I see entire data in the file, but it somehow misses the new line character and hence the data is
not inserted in the proper format in the file.
I know it is because of trailing '\0' but some how reducing the size by 1

```
(vlBuffer+=(vl_packetSize-PAD_SIZE-1);)
```

misses the new line character. fputs while putting the data removes the trailing null character
Please let me know what I am missing here to check or in the logic
(Note: I tried using strcat:

```
strcat(vlBuffer,vl_data+PAD_SIZE);
```

but I wanted to use memcpy as it is faster and also it can be used for any kind of buffer and not only character pointer

Thanks

Comment: Don't cast the return value from `malloc()` or `realloc()` in a C program.  You also don't need the casts in the `memset()` or `free()` calls.

Comment: Also, you should probably move `if(vlBuffer==NULL) return ERR_NO_MEM;` to happen before you use `memset` on `vlBuffer`.

Comment: @Carl Norum ,@Dcoder: Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed the code accordingly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` and `memcpy` are very different functions.
I suggest you read the documentation of each.

Mainly, there are two differences:
1. `memcpy` copies data where you tell it to. `strcat` finds the end of the string, and copies there.
2. `memcpy` copies the number of bytes you request. `strcat` copies until the terminating null.

If you're dealing with packets of arbitrary contents, you have no use for `strcat`, or other string functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the documentation for each. Your suggestion to use memcpy is perfectly the reason I am avoiding use of strcat.But the problem I mentioned before is somehow the null character is causing the fprintf and fputs function not to print or copy the entire content of vlBuffer. It stops at first null/'\0' value. If I reduce the size by which the buffer(pointer) is incremented by one , to overwrite the last null character, it also overwrites the new line character(if it has one). Thanks for the reply again

Comment: If you're not dealing with null-terminated strings, don't use any string functions. This includes `fprintf` and `fputs`. Use `write` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to the file in a binary-safe way. Check how to use fwrite instead of fputs. fwrite will copy all the buffer, even if there's a zero in the middle of it.

```
const char *mybuff= "Test1\0Test2";
const int mybuff_len = 11;
size_t copied = fwrite(mybuff, mybuff_len, 1, output_file);
```